# broken fonts on kubuntu kde [nvida] [kubuntu]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, kde, fonts

so i installed kubuntu and it has been pretty good so far but some time when i put my system to sleep or just leave it for a long time my fonts just like to brake some times they will just be boxes and some times they become rainbow puke 
system specs and software
newest NVIDIA driver 
gtx 1080
fx 8350
16 gbs of ram

[image: rainbow puke kde]